# iOS In App Purchase receipt Production or sandbox environment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, receipt

**REVIEW MESSAGE FROM APPLE**

"We found that your app has incorrectly implemented receipt validation, so it does not properly distinguish between the review (sandbox) environment and the production environment. This is resulting in a validation query to the production servers instead of a sandbox receipt check, and is preventing us from being able to review your app".

**OUR QUERY :**
We are verifying the receipts locally in the application.
On Subscription of an issue, we receive a receipt. Application doesn't know whether the receipt belongs to Sandbox or Production environment. Hence, app sends the receipt to Production server initially. Production server returns 21007 indicating that the receipt belongs to sandbox environment. Then we send the same to sandbox environment.Can you please clarify if this procedure was wrong ?

**After Subscription success Getting receipt:**

```
-(void)checkReceipt:(NSData *)receipt forProdictId:(NSString *) productid
 {
AppDelegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDel showProgressViewWithText:@“Please wait...”];

[ReceiptCheck validateReceiptWithData:receipt completionHandler:^(BOOL success,NSString *response)
{
    if(success==YES) 
    {
        [self updateReceipt:receipt withResponse:response];

    }
    else
    {

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate hideProgressView];
     }
  }
 }
```

----------------------------**Receipt Validation**----------------------------------

```
#import "ReceiptCheck.h"
#import "NSString+Base64.h"
#import "SBJSON.h"

#define SHARED_SECRET @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

#define RECEIPT_URL_SANDBOX @"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
#define RECEIPT_URL_PRODUCTION @"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"

@implementation ReceiptCheck

@synthesize receiptData,completionBlock;

+(ReceiptCheck *)validateReceiptWithData:(NSData *)_receiptData completionHandler:(void(^)(BOOL,NSString *))handler {
ReceiptCheck *checker = [[ReceiptCheck alloc] init];
checker.receiptData=_receiptData;
checker.completionBlock=handler;
[checker checkReceipt];
return checker;

}

-(void)checkReceipt {
 // verifies receipt with Apple
 NSError *jsonError = nil;
 NSString *receiptBase64 = [NSString base64StringFromData:receiptData length:[receiptData length]];

 //    NSLog(@"Receipt Base64: %@",receiptBase64);
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: receiptBase64,@"receipt-data", SHARED_SECRET,@"password", nil] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];

if(jsonError)
{
    completionBlock(NO,[jsonError localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:RECEIPT_URL_PRODUCTION];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:150];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

if(conn) 
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
} else 
{
    completionBlock(NO,@"Cannot create connection.");
}
}

 -(void)checkReceiptSandBox {
 // verifies receipt with Apple
 NSError *jsonError = nil;
 NSString *receiptBase64 = [NSString base64StringFromData:receiptData length:[receiptData length]];
  //    NSLog(@"Receipt Base64: %@",receiptBase64);
  //NSString *jsonRequest=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"receipt-data\":\"%@\"}",receiptBase64];
  //NSLog(@"Sending this JSON: %@",jsonRequest);

 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: receiptBase64,@"receipt-data", SHARED_SECRET,@"password", nil] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
 //NSLog(@"JSON: %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] );

if(jsonError)
{
    completionBlock(NO,[jsonError localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:RECEIPT_URL_SANDBOX];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:150];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

if(conn) 
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
} else 
{
    completionBlock(NO,@"Cannot create connection.");
}
}

 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
 {
completionBlock(NO,[error localizedDescription]);
 }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
[receivedData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
[receivedData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData* data = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *values = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];


if([values valueForKey:@"status"])
{
    if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21007)
    { // SAND BOX RECEIPT

        [self checkReceiptSandBox];
        return;
    }
}

completionBlock(YES,response);
 }

 @end
```

**After Update receipt:**

```
 - (void) updateReceipt:(NSData *)receipt  withResponse:(NSString *)response
 {
NSData* data = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

NSDictionary *values = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",values);


if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 0)
{
    NSString *strReceipt=@"";
    if([values valueForKey:@"latest_receipt"])
    {


        strReceipt = [values valueForKey:@"latest_receipt"];

        if([values valueForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"])
        {
            [self saveReceiptDetailsWithReceipt:strReceipt andReceiptInfo:values];

            NSString *strProductID = [[values valueForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"] valueForKey:@"product_id"];

            NSLog(@"%@",strProductID);
            WebServices *webService = [[WebServices alloc] init];
            webService.delegate=self;
            AppDelegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [appDel showProgressViewWithText:@"Please wait..."];
            webService.strSubscriptionProductID=strProductID;
            [webService afterSubscription:values andSubscriptionId:[self getSubscriptionIDForProductID:strProductID] receipt:strReceipt];
        }
    }
}
else if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21006)
{
    NSString *strReceipt=[NSString base64StringFromData:receipt length:[receipt length]];
    if([values valueForKey:@"latest_expired_receipt_info"])
    {
        [self saveReceiptDetailsWithReceipt:strReceipt andReceiptInfo:values];
    }
}
else if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21000)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"JSON Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The App Store could not read the JSON object you provided."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21002)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The data in the receipt-data property was malformed."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21003)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Receipt Authentication Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The receipt could not be authenticated."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21004)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Shared Secret Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The shared secret you provided does not match the shared secret on file for your account."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21005)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The receipt server is not currently available."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21007)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Receipt Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This receipt is a sandbox receipt, but it was sent to the production service for verification."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if([[values valueForKey:@"status"] integerValue] == 21008)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Receipt Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This receipt is a production receipt, but it was sent to the sandbox service for verification."] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
 }
```

Comment: That looks more-or-less right; does it work when you test it in the sandbox yourself? You should also check the status code returned from Apple to ensure it's 0 (meaning valid).

Comment: yes,I have checked my device it working fine But apple was rejected .i have checked status code also.

Comment: You might try reviewing Apple's helpful document on this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Comment: Any resolution to this? I have an app in review in a very similar state...